# MySQL Accented character

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Last week I migrated my db in another platform. I did a mysqldump export from phpmyadmin panel and then I imported it in a new platform using the bigdump script.
The sql dump file that I have imported was originally stored in a db that was setting in this manner:

```
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
MySQL connection collation: utf8_unicode_ci
```

I exported the db choosing utf8 character set but if I look inside the mysqldump file for every table appears:
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Now I have a problem with the accented letter (like à, è, ò, ì) that are displayed like Ã² , Ã...etc.
For manage my new db I use MySQL Workbench and if i prompt:
show variables like 'char%';
I see that all the values are set in utf8.
How can I solve the problem? I'm not a Mysql and db expert!

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the current character set of a table to the original:

```
alter table TABLE_NAME convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tables seem to use latin1, despite the utf8 settings you mentioned. So you have several options here:

1. Take the created dump as is and send it to the server using the latin1 connection charset (not utf8). This will however create the tables with latin1 charset as they are on the source server.
2. Convert the dump to utf-8 if you have a tool that can do it. You have to change the charset settings for your tables in the script too, though.
3. Convert your tables to utf8 and do the dump again.
4. Combine 1 + 3, but convert your target tables instead. Useful if you cannot change the source tables.

Have you actually tried MySQL Workbench to restore the dump to your new server? I'm quite sure it should be able to handle this case with a latin1 encoded backup. See Server Administration section -> Data Import/Restore.